# My steam account is logging into my old account, how do i fix

Tags: steam

My games on steam broke so to try and fix it I logged out of steam and moved the games to a separate hard drive. My games then broke. SO I decided to uninstall them and reinstall them only to find out I was logged into an old account of mine, I thought I must have loggged into it by accident. But when I went to re-log onto my new account it kept logging into my old one. Please help

Comment: Can't you just log out, log-in with the right one and let Steam remember it?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try uninstalling Steam, then reinstalling.

Comment: What do you mean by "broke"? That sounds like a quite significant underlying problem and might shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: There's something wrong.. if you log into account A then Steam wont log into Account B automatically. If you have several Accounts it's possible to share the game-librarys, keep that in mind

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on the issue you originally had with the games, and the steps you took?  Also, you said you moved the games to a separate hard drive, in my experience, Steam doesn't like it when you mess with its files, that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Just click at `Steam` > `Change User...` at the very top of your Steam Window.
Steam will logout and open the login window again.

then you can log in with your new account :)

[image: click here for an image of the dropdown menu]

Also:
It doesn't matter which account you use to install a game. When you install them with one account and then switch to another it will use the same game files and you dont need to reinstall it.

This also works when you haven't bought the game on that other account, Steam will show a `BUY`-Button instead of a  `PLAY`-Button in that case.

I hope that I helped you